# Populating HTML table from 2 different Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I am trying to create an HTML table from 2 different PHP arrays. Here are those arrays -

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test2
)
Array
(
    [0] => column1
    [1] => column2
)
```

I am creating those arrays like this -

```
$query = $_GET['query'];
$query_arr = explode(",", $query);
print_r($query_arr);
$boid = $_GET['boid'];
$boid_arr = explode(",", $boid);
print_r($boid_arr);
```

I need a table something like below -

```
DATA    COLUMN
test1   column1
test2   column2
```

I am not able to figure out how to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just use `array_combine` function. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>COLUMN</td>
    </tr>
<?php
// Add any markup that you need in `foreach`
foreach ($query_arr as $key => $value) {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$value?></td>
        <td><?=$boid_arr[$key]?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}?>
</table>
```